# Closure of boundary a boundary of closure.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Were ment to show that 
\begin{equation}
\overline {\delta A}=\delta \bar{A}
\end{equation}
$\bar{A}$ being the closure, $A^\circ$ being the interior   and $\delta$A being the boundary.
I've tried doing it at such:
\begin{align}
\overline {\delta A}=\delta A \cup\delta A=\delta A\\
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\delta\bar{A}=\delta(A\cup\delta A)=\overline {A\cup\delta A}\backslash(AU\delta A)^\circ=A\cup\delta A \backslash A^\circ
\end{align}
Now the last equal sign must be larger than $\delta A$ since $\delta A$ \ $A^\circ$ is an empty set, I am adding something to $\delta A$, hence it must be larger than  $\delta A$.
Yet it seems wrong for example if I Drive a set in R$^2$ with a missing line, the inclusion doesn't seem to work.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. If $A=\mathbb Q$ then $\delta (A)=\mathbb R$ and $\delta \overline {A} =\emptyset$,

Comment: What is the closure of $\mathbb R$ and what is its interior? @Mark